# cross hair cursor in pyqtgraph is slow

Tags: pyqtgraph

In a pyqtgraph.PlotWidget I have a curves plotted, about 2000 points each.
Also there is a cross-hair cursor implemented using InfiniteLines.
When the mouse moves the lines are moved using their setPos function.
Doing this causes all of the curves to be repainted.
This is slow, so the cursor lags way behind the user movements.
I've set the SignalProxy delay to 0, and also tried not using SignalProxy at all. It is the repaint of the curves that is causing the delay.

Is there any way to move the lines without causing a repaint of all the curves?